# Avoid using with() in user generated filter for JSONstat

Tags: javascript, json, dataset, deprecated, with-statement

I am creating graph from dataset that is filtered through users filter requirments. To filter data we are using JSONstat like this:

```
const data = JSONstat(j).Dataset(1).toTable({type: 'arrobj'}, filterFunction);
```

toTable takes a callback for example like this

```
 function( d, i ){
      if( d.age==="total" ){
        return d;
      }
    }
```

[source](https://github.com/jsonstat/toolkit/blob/master/docs/API.md#totable)

It is wanted for the user to be able input his own filter criteria but without the object reference. For example just inputing `city === "New York"` or `city === "Chicago" && year==="2012"`

This is currently accomplished similiary as the following example where `filter` is the user input:

```
const filterFunction = eval(`(d, i) => { with(d) return (${filter}) ? d : undefined }`);
```

This works well but obviously `with()` is depricated and it's usage is discouraged.

Is there a way to accomplish this without the `with()` statement and perhaps without parsing the user inputed string and then putting it back together with the object notation?

I've tried using IIE which would ussually help with the scope issue regarding `with()`but this doesn't help when the user input is unkown.

Comment: `with` is not going anywhere. Do not use it in your own code, but within a temporary eval function - why not?

Comment: otherwise, parsing the input is the only option, and you're going to need it anyway, for example, to notify the user of possible syntax errors.

Comment: @gog thanks for the reply. I assumed I might have to parse it anyway. Was checking if am I not missing anything. Cheers.